# indexing one dataframe with another

Tags: r

I have the following subset of two long `data.frame`:

```
df1 <- data.frame("trial" = c('SA1','SA2','ES1','SA3','SA4','ES5'), "Genotype" = c('GID1','GID1','GID1','GID2','GID2','GID2'))
df2 <- data.frame('GID1'= c('0','1'),'GID2'=c('1','0'))
```

What I would like to do is, I want to index `df1$Genotype` column by `df2` colnames and expand `df2` columns by substituting the values of `df1$trial` as new columns in `df2`.

So as a result I would have `df3` as an expansion of `df2` as follows :

```
df3 <- data.frame('SA1'=c(0,1), 'SA2'=c(0,1), 'ES1'=c(0,1), 'SA3'= c(1,0),'SA4'=c(1,0),'ES5'=c(1,0))
```

Please note the `data.frame` is huge and I've tried functions like `match` and `%in%` without success.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easier than it seems:

```
df3 <- df2[df1$Genotype]
colnames(df3) <- df1$trial
df3
#   SA1 SA2 ES1 SA3 SA4 ES5
# 1   0   0   0   1   1   1
# 2   1   1   1   0   0   0
```

All we need to do is to select correct columns from `df1` for each row of `df1`, and my first line does exactly that.

Comment: wow thanks. Could you explain me what is the purpose of subsetting a dataframe without a comma . this is something new to me, I always thought that when subsetting a dataframe you should either subset by rows or columns. thanks

Comment: @AlexandreMondaini, you are indeed right, here I'm subsetting by columns. However, it happens that you can get, e.g., the first column with both `df1[, 1]` and `df1[1]`. One intuitive reason for that is that data frames are actually lists consisting of elements (columns) of equal lengths. So, indeed the first line could be just `df3 <- df2[, df1$Genotype]`.